# Convert mains voltage to analog input level with the least amount of parts

Tags: mains, converter

For a future product I will utilize analog input PCB mounted modules from Beckhoff that can measure either **0-10V single ended, -10+10V differential, 0-20mA and 4-20mA** signals.

I would like to measure the momentary actual voltage level of mains line power potentials (**110-240V AC**) in order to gain required data on the current phase of the alternating voltage.

For my application, minimum complexity has priority. All in one elements are preferred over general purpose components.

**What are some good ways to convert the mains line voltage level to any of these possible analog inputs with the least amount of additional components while retaining adequate protection?**
Would also appreciate some suggestions concerning possible suitable components.

---

I did some research on the (getting harder to search) web and came across the known possibility of Optocouplers and Transformers. The former needing considerable additional parts around it to operate and to be linear and the later being harder to find a suitable one. Also looked for integrated circuit components that were specialized for this task but didn't really find anything.

Considering fault protection, the analog input modules have plenty of protection integrated inside themselves, the line side less so.

Beckhoff does offer modules for this purpose but those are not PCB mount and would require additional overhead due to that.

Comment: How unsafe are you willing for it to be? Because two resistors will do it but horribly unsafe for both you and the equipment.

Comment: "*I would like to measure the momentary actual voltage level ...*" That is going to give you a reading between \$ -V_{pk}\$ an \$+V_{pk}\$ depending on the moment the sample is taken and that will probably be determined by the analog input and will be outside of your control. I don't think this is what you want. I suggest that you rewrite your specification and if you want to know the RMS mains voltage then specify the measurement time period allowed. It's going to have to be > half a mains cycle.

Comment: a "wall wart" may work

Comment: @Transistor The exact timing of the sample is determinable trough the use of the EtherCat bus. I require the momentary voltage information for my application, the RMS Voltage is already available trough information gained from smart power supplies.

Comment: @DKNguyen For, for instance, the EJ3108, allows for max. 30V on the input, I remembered some other modules that had overcurrent protection. They surely have a couple of diodes in there though. While the mains are just behind a circuit breaker and probably an additional fuse. If some further components are required, so be it but at least I can compare the solution to others then.

Comment: Diodes can't clamp mains voltage on their own. They will fry. Diodes and a resistor can, but if that one resistor fails everything still blows and then becomes hazardous to you if you happen to be operating it. Fuses and breakers are useless for protecting electronic equipment from frying. Breakers are for preventing fires.

Comment: Well I was expecting at least a transistor or optocoupler in there or for it to be integrated in an IC ... now I understand what you were getting at, ha. I though you meant additional to something else. No it doesn't need to be just two resistors. But yeah, that's one solution. Thanks. :D

Comment: For what it's worth differential probes have no isolation and essentially rely on resistive dividers but they use many resistors in series so if a single resistor fails the reading goes haywire but the voltage is still stepped down low enough that the equipment doesn't fry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to measure the *instantaneous* AC mains voltage, something like an isolation amplifier should do the job. Often they require an isolated supply so you would add a DC-DC converter rated appropriately. If they don't they're typically larger and much more expensive.

[The AMC1350](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/amc1350-q1.pdf) is the first one I happened to look up, so it may not be optimal on any particular account, but it should be illustrative:

[image]

Omitted from the above diagram is the DC-DC converter for the high-side supply (or you could derive a supply from the mains voltage using a power supply module of some kind). The voltage divider needs to be rated for mains voltage operation (including transients) and the ratio should reduce the mains voltage to the +/-5V range of this particular chip. The bandwidth of this part is several hundred kHz so it should not affect the phase much.

If you want to proceed in this manner, determine your actual requirements a bit better, and do a parametric search for this kind of part and evaluate the various possibilities.

Comment: To eliminate the need for a separate isolated supply, there are some iso amps that have them integrated - for example, the AD215: https://www.analog.com/en/products/ad215.html#product-overview

Comment: @Synchrondyne That's quite illustrative of the size and cost differences I mentioned. 10x the price and >50x bigger. A nice trouble-free solution though, if you can find them in stock. I've used the predecessor model and it worked well in the application.

Comment: This is the kind of component I didn't knew about and it fits the described requirements spot on! I stayed up for a few hours to go over all the ones I could find and the selection doesn't seem very broad but there are (is) affordable ones even with integrated DC-DC converter like the AMC3330 and they just require some resistors and capacitors around them, when using multiple amplifiers going with a separate isolated DC-DC converter also makes sense.
It's true though that this made me realize I didn't specify enough yet, even if the device will be SELV or PELV.